# C++ GetUserName() returning username and gibberish

Tags: c++, windows-7

I want to get the username of the current process. I am using the winapi standard `GetUsername` function like so:

```
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
```

and printing it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= UNLEN; i++) if(isalpha(username[i])) cout << (char)(username[i]);
```

but it outputs

Nickiê╕♣■scm+♣■pα┬p♠■≡î■ └M♣■╧*■╔       ■♣ÿ(♣♣(♣♣♣♣    T♣@♣3♣■┐

`Nicki` is the username of the system I am testing on.
I do not know what I am doing wrong. It compiles fine, and I am including

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
```

these headers.

Can someone please help!

Comment: 256 as defined in `Lmcons.h`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am showing every line of code in my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i <= UNLEN; i++) if(isalpha(username[i])) cout << (char)(username[i]);
```

You should say

```
for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) if(isalpha(username[i])) cout << (char)(username[i]);
```

Because `GetUserName` figures out the length of the actual username and passes it back to `size` (that is why it is passed by reference). The full `username` array is 257 elements long, so it will let you `cout` all of them, which most of them are nonsense.

From the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> lpnSize [in, out]
>      On input, this variable specifies the size of the lpBuffer buffer, in TCHARs. **On output, the variable receives the number of TCHARs copied to the buffer, including the terminating null character**.

Answer (score 3):

After the call, your buffer `username` contains a 0-terminated string of length `size-1`. Any bytes beyond the terminating 0 are arbitrary garbage. Your code depends on these wrong premises:

- usernames only contain letters (`isalpha()`). Digits and underscores are some of the possible additional characters.
- the string is zero-padded to buffer length. Actually, any arbitrary garbage may follow the string.
- TCHAR is char. Are you sure neither UNICODE nor _UNICODE is defined?

better use

```
    cout << username;
```

to print your string.

Tip: Only type-cast if needed, and only after careful consideration to make sure it is actually correct.

Comment: yeah, I was just using the isalpha to filter out junk.

Comment: I am honestly curious why 'isalpha' still printed the garbled characters?  When I try typing in a string with extended chars like "╕" I do NOT get those printed, even with the longer length.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even know why the function returns gibberish in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `UNLEN` characters and ignoring modified `size` parameter so you get the gibberish that is in buffer.

Comment: I have no way to know the length of the username... returned is the success boolean.

Comment: You got the size parameter modified also the string is zero-terminated  so you have two ways to determine its length.